# Download dependencies in the target folder

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-plugin

Is there any way I can download the dependencies directly in the target folder without changing the localrepository in the settings.xml?

Comment: Why would you like to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the maven-dependency-plugin. Have a look at https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html for an example.